# Supplemental Insurance for Martial Arts Students

Tags: united-states, insurance, health-insurance

I would like to know if there are supplemental insurance policies for people who study martial arts (living in the United States). Specifically, I would like to find a policy that covers injuries that occur during training. Like other sports and hobbies martial arts training can carry risks even if you don't compete (a broken nose, a torn ACL, etc.) I can't find anything through normal online searches, so my supposition is that this kind of coverage is too high risk for most insurance companies to offer. Still, I would love to be proven wrong.

Edit: I am not an instructor -- that kind of insurance is for liability. I am a student of martial arts. Also, I realize that injuries are covered by most insurance carriers, but if you have a high deductible plan the coverage may not kick in before several thousand dollars are spent. I'm looking for something that can fill the gap.

Comment: Wouldn't this be covered under a regular health insurance plan?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: What is your role? Are you the owner of the business; the instructor; the parent; the student; or somebody who wants to sell insurance?

Comment: I am living in the United States, and yes this is covered by regular insurance, except that many plans require you to meet a high deductible before coverage kicks in. I'm looking for something that can fill that gap. No, I am not an instructor --- insurance for that purpose is different. I will edit the question to better reflect my intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of insurance is called Supplemental Accident Insurance.  It covers expenses related to an injury that are not covered by your regular health insurance.  Alternatively, some plans simply pay out a set amount for each type of injury.

You can find lots of companies offering this type of insurance by searching ["supplemental accident insurance"](https://www.google.com/search?q=supplemental+accident+insurance).  Probably the best well known in the U.S. is Aflac, due to their constant television advertising.

Injuries due to high-risk activites (such as sky diving) are typically excluded, but martial arts is not typically excluded.  You should read the fine print of any policy you are considering to make sure.  I'm not aware of any policies that *only* cover martial arts injuries.

For most people, this type of insurance is not worth getting.  Instead, I would recommend setting some money aside as an emergency fund to pay for unexpected injury.  If you have a High Deductible Health Plan, you can set up a Health Saving Account (HSA), which you can use to pay for medical expenses not covered by your health insurance tax-free.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I will look into both options.

Comment: @rclowery624 I just reworded my answer, because looking at what I wrote, it sounded like I was saying that martial arts is typically excluded.  Actually it is *not* typically excluded.

Comment: @rclowery624 Regardless of one's risk level, anyone with a HDHP should be using a HSA.  In fact, I was always under the impression that the only reason anyone *ever* got a HDHP was specifically in order to be able to create a HSA.  In any case, if you anticipate lots of martial arts injuries, you might consider signing up for a Low Deductible Health Plan instead.

Comment: @dg99 Yes, I hear you. I initially intended to set up a HSA when I signed up for my company's insurance plan, however because I work by remote, and because the bank that they use does not exist where I live, I didn't. Is it possible to set up an HSA with another bank that your company does not support or use?

Comment: @rclowery624 Yes, if you are covered by an HSA-eligible HDHP, you can set up an HSA with any bank or credit union that you want.  Your employer might not contribute to it, but anything you contribute to it can be excluded from your income at tax time, subject to the HSA contribution rules.  If you have any more questions about HSAs, feel free to [ask a new question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).